# how to use selectOneMenu with object in selectItems

Tags: java, composite, selectonemenu

I don`t understand how to use **ArrayList** of objects in f:selectitems.
I use composite components and code below is not work:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="kladrRegion-dctKladrRegion" 
                                     tabindex="100"
                                     value="#{cc.attrs.kladrRegion}"
                                     styleClass="comboBox ui-corner-all   inputText ui-inputfield kladrSearchFormInput kladrSearchFormSelectWidth selectHight"  
                                     style="font-size: 13px; width: 300px;"
                                     binding="#{cc.attrs.cbKladrRegion}" >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.kladrRegions}" var="region" 
                                       itemLabel="#{region.value}" itemValue="#{region.id}" />                                
                        <f:ajax  
                            listener="#{cc.attrs.kladrRegionChange}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

This code does not work, because the attribute var receive a new value after adding a second composite component. In the previous composite components **selectOneMenu** will not be displayed.
How to make a drop-down list in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of my problem. Follow to this post:  [JSF 2 composites and binding for validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709831/jsf-2-composites-and-binding-for-validation)

SelectOneMenu needs to have "binding" attribute with unique value. 
[After adding second composite component Error <f:ajax> contains an unknown id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608408/after-adding-second-composite-component-error-fajax-contains-an-unknown-id)